# Why write function not working in realm on swift?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Working with *realm 5.3.0* on *swift 5.2*. I have 2 cases: when I want to add new item to table and when I want to update. Function `realm.add(_:update:)` have to solve my problem, but item is creating and cannot updating. When I try to update, I got:

> Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first.

There are method, where I calling write function:

```
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(note, update: .modified)
}
```

And model:

```
class Note: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var descr : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var dateTime : Date = Date()
    
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
      return "id"
    }
    
    init(id: String, name: String, descr: String, dateTime: Date) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.descr = descr
        self.dateTime = dateTime
    }
    
    required init() {}
}
```

Comment: Which line of code is throwing that error?

Comment: You should probably fix your realm object. Remove `required init() {}`. Then the init method should be `convenience init` with the first line being `self.init()`. Oh - also insure you are populating your primary key with something, not just "". Like `@objc dynamic var id : String = UUID().uuidString`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to update your object inside write scope instead of using realm.add command again. Realm will automatically update the object in database

```
try! realm.write {
   //Modify Node here
}
```

Comment: The same error. And I need to update if exists and create if not.

Comment: You need to load the node first from realm by using realm.objects and filter commands

Comment: Isn't that the same code the OP has in their question? Also realm.add can be used to update objects as well as long as they have primary keys (which these do). See [Objects with primary keys](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#objects-with-primary-keys)